# Why are Normal maps not Baking/Rendering correctly

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I've baked my normals from a high poly mesh on the low poly Version UVs are matching (I think) yet there are these odd looking Artefacts in my normal map, Why could this be?

[image: Normalmap]

[[image: low poly with normal][2]]